# What is Premier Support?

Tags: force.com, dev401

What is meant by Salesforce Premier Support ? How much does it cost ?

I am preparing for salesforce developer certification, can having premier support help me ?

Comment: Listed pricing is 15% of your licensing costs for Premier and 25% for Premier+. So if you're paying $100k/year in SFDC licensing, Premier+ would run you and additional $25,000/year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is certain developer-focussed on-line training that is ONLY available to Premier Customers (customers who pay an additional fee for Premier services including support). I believe that you need to be a Premier customer to be eligible and then they are free. You will need to get in touch with Salesforce about pricing for Premier upgrade. There are also in-person classes that you can attend, see the training section in Salesforce.  The alternative is to self study. Follow the study guide issued by Salesforce to help you prepare for the Salesforce Certified Developer Exam (DEV401).   [Salesforce DEV401 Study Guide](http://certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedDeveloper.pdf?v=8)

Also, here is a link to [Force.com Fundamentals](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force_Platform_Fundamentals) which is very useful at getting you started.
Best of luck!

Answer (score 11):

I think you mean Premier Support, which has a few benefits:

1. When you log a case, support will contact you within two (2) hours
2. When you log a case you don't start at the lowest support level, but one up
3. You have access to an extended collection of training videos. These videos can be used to just about cover everything in the ADM201 course and then some
4. You have access to training templates that you can use in your company

If you're looking to get the developer certification, DEV401, I would suggest reading through Salesforce's published study guides. They provide links to good training resources and a breakdown of the topics on the test.

**Edit**

I forgot to address the cost aspect of the question. There is an additional cost, which is generally a percentage of your per-user license cost and either your entire org has premier support or it doesn't; you cannot purchase it on a per-user basis. Exact pricing should be discussed with your account executive.